# Do we need retry logic for AWS EC2 instance metadata api calls?

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-ec2, metadata, instance

When obtaining the instance region from the AWS EC2 instance metadata service we have seen a call return 403 not found. This behaviour is not common but when it does happen the instance won't launch correctly as the userdata script relies on knowing the region.

I'm just wondering what people do in this case? Do you say ohwell it's a one off lets terminate the instance, or do you have retry logic with a backoff to improve the chances of success?

Error log: `Unable to retrieve Host Instance PublicIPv4 Address: EC2MetadataError: failed to make EC2Metadata request\n\tstatus code: 404`

Thanks

Comment: That is a most unusual situation! The metadata is provided by the Hypervisor and does not traverse the network. Therefore, I would have thought that it is inconceivable that it would fail to be available. I have never seen a mention of people having this problem.

Comment: Yeah it's strange, the log says 

Unable to retrieve Host Instance PublicIPv4 Address: EC2MetadataError: failed to make EC2Metadata request\n\tstatus code: 404

Comment: Just wondering if it has Instance Metadata **v2** turned on, which might deny the earlier version of Instance Metadata? I haven't tried that myself.